# Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly?

Tags: python

I am making rock paper scissors and when I run it it says "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly".

```
import time
import random
print("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors?")
playerscore = 0
cpuscore = 0
game = input()
game = game.upper()
while game == "SURE" or game == "YES" or game == "YEAH": # starts rock                                 paper scissors
    number = random.randint(1, 3)
    if number == 1:
        cpurpors = "SCISSORS"
    elif number == 2:
        cpurpors = "ROCK"
    elif number == 3:
        cpurpors = "PAPER"
    print("Cool! Rock, paper or scissors?")
    rpors = input()
    rpors = rpors.upper()
    print("Rock")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Paper")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Scissors")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(cpurpors + "!")
    time.sleep(.5)
    if cpurpors == rpors:
        print("Draw!")
    elif cpurpors == "SCISSORS" and rpors == "PAPER" or cpurpors == "PAPER" and rpors == "ROCK" or cpurpors == "ROCK" and rpors == "SCISSORS":
        cpuscore = cpuscore + 1
        print("Haha, I win!")
    elif rpors == "SCISSORS" and cpurpors == "PAPER" or rpors == "PAPER" and cpurpors == "ROCK" or rpors == "ROCK" and cpurpors == "SCISSORS":
        playerscore = playerscore + 1
        print("Oh no! You win!")
    print("The scores are:")
    print("Guiseppebot: " + cpuscore)
    print(name + ": " + playerscore)
    print("Would you like to play again?")
    game = input()
    game = game.upper()
```

Comment: Can you include the error output?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Guiseppebot Simulator (1).py", line 128, in <module>
    print("Guiseppebot: " + cpuscore)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" error (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133311/cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly-error-python)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're adding `int` variables to the print statements. Try doing something like this:

```
print(name + ": " + str(playerscore))
```

In that example, you're setting `playerscore` to the `string` version of the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Need to wrap the integers `cpuscore` and `playerscore` with `str` to convert them to a string, as it won't do it implicitly.

```
print("Guiseppebot: " + str(cpuscore))
print(name + ": " + str(playerscore))
```

Another nice option is using format, which does call `str` on objects for you so you don't have to worry about it in the future:

```
print("Guiseppebot: {}".format(cpuscore))
print("{}: {}".format(name, playerscore))
```

`str` is the built-in function that will convert non string objects to a string. It does this by calling the objects `.__str__` method if it exists (and knows how to otherwise for objects like ints and floats.) Read more about it in the docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str

Comment: please can you explain what str means?

Comment: @WSingleton sure, added to answer: `str` is the built-in function that will convert non string objects to a string. It does this by calling the objects `__str__` method if it exists (and knows how to otherwise for objects like ints and floats.)

Answer (score 0):

`cpuscore` is an integer(`int`) it can't be concatenated with a string. Python doesn't convert it to a string automatically("implicitly"). So you at least need to do:

```
print("Guiseppebot: " + str(cpuscore))
```

Even better/easier, in Python 3.6+, use  [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
Assuming you *can* put the value inside a variable into a string (integers, strings, lists, dictionaries are ok), you just put them inside curly brackets.

Here's how the line with that error looks with f-strings:

```
print(f"Guiseppebot: {cpuscore}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm nor sure if this is the best solution, but my approach would be to use str() to convert the integer (cpuscore) to a string.

```
import time
import random
name = input ("what's your name? ") #added in input for variable (name)
print("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors?")
playerscore = 0
cpuscore = 0
game = input()
game = game.upper()
while game == "SURE" or game == "YES" or game == "YEAH": # starts rock                                 paper scissors
    number = random.randint(1, 3)
    if number == 1:
        cpurpors = "SCISSORS"
    elif number == 2:
        cpurpors = "ROCK"
    elif number == 3:
        cpurpors = "PAPER"
    print("Cool! Rock, paper or scissors?")
    rpors = input()
    rpors = rpors.upper()
    print("Rock")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Paper")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Scissors")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(cpurpors + "!")
    time.sleep(.5)
    if cpurpors == rpors:
        print("Draw!")
    elif cpurpors == "SCISSORS" and rpors == "PAPER" or cpurpors == "PAPER" and rpors == "ROCK" or cpurpors == "ROCK" and rpors == "SCISSORS":
        cpuscore = cpuscore + 1
        print("Haha, I win!")
    elif rpors == "SCISSORS" and cpurpors == "PAPER" or rpors == "PAPER" and cpurpors == "ROCK" or rpors == "ROCK" and cpurpors == "SCISSORS":
        playerscore = playerscore + 1
        print("Oh no! You win!")
    print("The scores are:")
    print("Guiseppebot: " + str(cpuscore)) #converted cpuscore to a string
    print(name + ": " + str(playerscore)) #variable (name) wasn't declared
    print("Would you like to play again?")
    game = input()
    game = game.upper()
```